# Edit Excel File in Stored in Resources

Tags: c#, excel, winforms

Trying to edit my Excel template that is stored in my resources. When I get to the line that actually inserts text into the resource file: `ws.Cells["C1"].Value = "TestText";`, I get an error that says "System.ArgumentException: 'The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))'"  How can I solve this problem?

```
  private void exceltest()
        {
            Excel._Workbook excelWorkbook;
            //save resource to disk
            string pathz = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
            string filepath = pathz + @"\resource.xltx";
            //string strPathToResource = @"c:\resource.xltx";
            using (FileStream cFileStream = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Create))
            {
                cFileStream.Write(Resources.resource, 0, Resources.resource.Length);
            }

            //open workbook
            Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
            excelWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(filepath);
            if (excelWorkbook == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: Unable to open Excel file.");
                return;
            }
            Excel.Worksheet ws = excelWorkbook.ActiveSheet;
            ws.Cells["C1"].Value = "TestText";
           
            xlApp.Visible = true;
        }
```

Comment: The null-check on `excelWorkbook` should probably move before the assignment of `ws`, otherwise you'll stills trow that NRE you're trying to prevent.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon just updated it, still getting the same error.

Comment: @okra: Mathieu's comment was a tangential review note, not a solution. That `null` check is pointless. If it can't open the file, it'll thrown an exception rather than returning `null`. You need a try/catch block to handle such an error... which is unrelated to the one you're asking about.

Comment: See the [documentation for the indexer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.item) on the `Cells` property. (Hint: "C1" is not what it expects.)

Comment: @madreflection Thanks, this solved my issue, would upvote if I could!

Comment: I'm voting to close as a typo because all you needed to do was read the documentation in order write the correct thing.